# Running a Sandybridge i5 2500K on an h67 board

Tags: cpu, integrated-graphics, chipset

Is anyone aware of any issues/downsides of running a Sandy Bridge i5 2500K on an H67 board?

Some info for context:

- I'm planning on building a dual
  monitor, quiet, development rig.
- I have no plans to do any
  overclocking.
- I have no plans to do any gaming on
  the rig ( if that changes I'll add a
  dedicated card)

The reason I'm looking at the K CPU is that it comes with the 3000 version of the integrated GPU, rather than the 2000 on the other i5s. This is important to me because I want to take advantage of the H67 chipsets ability to support dual monitors using the integrated GPU.

Some downsides that I am aware of:

- The 2500K is a great overclocking CPU
  but by pairing with an H67 chipset I
  lose the abilty to take advantage of
  that

Comment: What kind of "issues/downsides"?  You seem aware that you lose overclocking ability and gain integrated graphics, that's really the only difference that matters.

Comment: I'm not really a hardware guy, I've been digging around for a few days and gathered some information but there is so much out there I thought I'd crowd source in case I missed anything. Something like "OMG don't do that it'll run so hot it will melt through to the core of the earth" kind of thing.

Comment: If that were the case, Intel wouldn't support it. :)  You're fine, but I don't really think there's anything to be said on this topic, haha.

Comment: +1  "OMG don't do that it'll run so hot it will melt through to the core of the earth"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering primarily for the benefit of future searchers.

It would appear there are no downsides known to the community other than those outlined in the question.

Comment: Have you tried using the onboard GPU *and* a separate graphics card simultaneously? I've heard conflicting rumors about whether or not this will work. A lot of the older chipsets with integrated GPUs would automatically disable the integrated GPU when you plugged in a video card. Is Sandy Bridge the same way? (I'm a dev too, but I need 4 monitors!)

Comment: @Cody I've not tried it, I've found the on board GPU to be more than enough for me. You may want to look into the AMD eyefinity or similar tech to get the 4 monitors off one graphics card.